# angularjs protractor 3.3.0 not reporting specs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I don't see expected output for a passed run, the assertions are not listed. I expect to see the assertion in this line "1 spec, 0 failures".

The output:

```
  [18:28:06] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
  [18:28:06] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
  Started
  .


  1 spec, 0 failures
  Finished in 0.854 seconds
  [18:28:08] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
  [18:28:08] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Expected end of run output as seen on protractor's web site, http://www.protractortest.org/#/ "Run the test"):

```
  1 test, 3 assertions, 0 failures
```

The spec:

```
  describe('Viewing index.html', function() {
  'use strict';


   beforeEach(function(){
     browser.get('/');
   });

   it('should have pages in left nav', function() {
      expect(element.all(by.repeater('page in adminClient.selectedSite.pages')).count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

  });
```

I verified that the by.repeater locator worked:

```
  element.all(by.repeater('page in adminClient.selectedSite.pages')).count()
         .then(function(count){
            console.log('page count: ' + count);
      });
```

[UPDATE] According to this SO, it is a version issue and there is a recommendation to inject jasmine reporters on the onPrepare hook but that created more runtime errors for me.
[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771297/protractor-test-doesnt-have-test-and-assertion-output-and-instead-just-has-spec/34777540)

My protractor config:

```
  exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    chromeOnly: true,
    chromeDriver: 'node_modules/protractor/bin/selenium/chromedriver_2.21',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['tests/e2e/*-spec.js'],
    capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8889/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
  };
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what errors have you got while trying the `jasmine-reporters`?

Comment: @WillLopez please see my posted answer; did this resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the spec names and assertions you must pass the `--verbose` flag to protractor. If you are using grunt or something to run protractor, you'll need to specify this flag in your config.

**EDIT**
After reading your edit I believe I have found the solution to your issue. I've tried it with a project of my own and it appears to work.

The underlying problem is that you are likely using protractor 3, which no longer supports many of the previous options particularly within `jasmineNodeOpts`. To correct this issue, you should downgrade your version of protractor to 2, the latest version is 2.5.1

[Here's the related issue on protractor's github repository](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1789). It also mentions a custom reporter within the onPrepare hook like you were talking about, but a different one: `jasmine-spec-reporter`. I got that working as well with a slightly different configuration than what you are using but it does not display the assertions, just has a much better output for the tests, which I quite like:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  print: function () {} // remove dots for each test
},

onPrepare: function () {
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStackTrace: true}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel_Cottone for the response but that isn't what I'm looking for & it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: @WillLopez Please see my updated solution, I have tested it and it works.